# How to create multiple user in Php?

Tags: php

Here's my table in database :

[image]

Then this is my code :

```
            <tr>
              <td width="50">
                <div align="right">Username</div>
              </td>
              <td width="100">
              <input name="username" type="text" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div align="right">Password</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input name="password" type="password" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="w3-select" name="option">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>User Type
                  </option>
                    <option value="1">Admin
                    </option>
                    <option value="2">Doctor
                    </option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div align="right"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input name="" type="submit" value="Login" />
              </td>
            </tr>
```

The problem is how can I call admin.php when I click admin in the user type? 
Or should i remove usertype in html/php and should base in database? thank you so much

Comment: please add the data here rather than posting to an image of the database. this should include the structure of the table. if the image is taken down for any reason it invalidates the question.

In this case however the data is not overly relevant. Have you made any start with the PHP.

Hint for the PHP you should be looking at $_GET['option'] or $_POST['option'] dependant upon which method is used to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `<form>` where you pass the data as `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables.

Something like this:

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enter restricted area">
</form>
```

Since this code uses `method="post"`, the input data will then be stored in the global `$_POST` variable. This means that in `admin.php` you can access them as `$_POST["username"]` and `$_POST["password"]`.

I suggest you to read the tutorial: [PHP forms tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

PS: For better security, you should not store the password in the database. Instead, encrypt it with a hash algorithm and store the encrypted version: [password_verify manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)